# Salesforce Individuals Email Results From Address Dynamic sender profile

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

We have Sales cloud-integrated to Marketing cloud using MCC. Every lead has an advisor. when a lead status is set to "Qualified" in sales cloud, he enters a journey in the marketing cloud. The subscriber key is salesforce lead id.

Now sender profile used for sending is dynamic. In the profile attribute, we have all lead along with their advisor info. based on subscriber , From address name and From address email is picked. Then email goes. Email goes with correct email and name based on subscriber. All good till here

When the tracking data is synced back to sales cloud, inside Individuals Email Results on those email, we see that From address is not correct email address or name. Its the backup email used in sender profile.

any tips on resolving this

Thanks
Shekhar

Comment: This doesn't seem to be programming-related so your question will probably get closed / downvoted to oblivion. Administrator stuff is best asked at dedicated salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: eyescream not sure if you understand the question. its not a strategy question. This functionality is based on marketing cloud, thus could you share when you want to close the question, which doesn't seem to be correct unless you let me know.